# show that rational numbers with the multipiciation are not abelian finitely generated group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

we need to show that $( Q \ast , \bullet )$ is not abelian finitely generated group for all finite subset $S \subseteq Q \ast $

$ Q\ast=Q \setminus  \big\{0\big\} $

Comment: Given a finite set $S \subseteq Q \ast $, we can write $S = \{\frac{p_1}{q_1},\ldots, \frac{p_n}{q_n}\}$. Now consider the prime factors of $p_i$ and $q_i$ to construct a rational number not in the group generated by $S$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

The subgroup generated by $\left(\frac{p_1}{q_1},\frac{p_2}{q_2},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right)$ doesn't contain $\frac{1}{1+q_1 q_2\cdots q_n}$.

Comment: and why is so? cant proof that

Comment: If $\frac{p}{q}$ is a rational in this subgroup then the prime divisors of $q$ divide at least one of $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ so they divide $q_1q_2\cdots q_n$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: im sorry but i didnt get it yet, eventhough you know this fact about the prime divisors of q, how does it affect you for putting: q1q2⋯qn+1 in the denominator...
sorry about my misunderstaning, i am new to this type of questions

Comment: If $\frac{1}{1+q_1 q_2\cdots q_n}$ is in this subgroup  a prime that divides the denominator $1+q_1 q_2\cdots q_n$ and it divides also $q_1 q_2\cdots q_n$ would divides the difference $1$ which gives a contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps what's lacking here is to remind the OP that the group operation is *multiplication*, so every element in that finitely generated subgroup is a **product** of the generators, each raised to some power...and this cannot "give" new primes besides the $\;p_j's\,,\,q_i$'s in generators

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** Assume $\mathbb{Q}$ is finitely generated. $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, so apply the [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group). After some thought, this will lead you to finding a relationship between $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Then what do you conclude about $\mathbb{Q}$? Is that possible?

Comment: The OP's question is about $\;\Bbb Q%*\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I fail how to see how my answer fails to lead him to a possible solution.

Comment: Again, you're not even working with the group the OP mentioned, and even then the comparison between $\;\Bbb Z^n\,,\,\Bbb Q\;$ can be a little tough for someone asking an elementary question. Just read the OP's comments below the other answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am using the group the OP mentions. This method can be used to show $(\mathbb{Q},\times)$ or $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ are not finitely generated. As for this being a non-elementary method, that may be true. However, this was how I first learned to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated. Someone has already given a more 'elementary' method, so I need not. It is good to have/know multiple ways of solving a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to notice that, according to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \times)$ is precisely the abelian free group of rank $\aleph_0$.